# Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.picture1

Tags: android, bitmap

I am a beginner in Android programming and I very often encounter the error of "cannot be resolved or is not a field" whenever I refer to the other resources...

One example is below, from an `android.view.View` class:

```
import android.R;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;


@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation") public class UserView extends View {
    public UserView(Context context){
        super(context);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.picture1);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0,0, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: [r] i a tag for the statistical programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have

```
import android.R;
```

that R class certainly doesn't have your resources defined. You should import com.example.abc.R. com.example.abc is your package name

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. I wonder if I should study this topic further... The 'import' part is always a problem... Where shall I start with? I am reading a book for self-study, but there is little information regarding the 'import' part'. Every time I just use the quick fix and try my luck.

Comment: I think using quick fix is ok. And remember to accept my answer please